# How to bend UV Map?

Tags: uv

I guess the correct procedure is create uv map 1st then drew texture onto it

but I have a texture in the 1st place and I want bend the uv grip to match it
is there a way to bend it into a curve without move ever point? since it not very nice.

[image]

Comment: I might try creating a cylinder, deleting one end, unwrapping all with no seams, then deleting the other end. That will create a UV map in the shape of a cutout circle, but the mesh is cylindrical. Delete one-half of the mesh ring, and there you should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a basis shape key and a second shape key, then modify this second shape key so that it looks like your UV circle arc (you can use your image in the 3D view as *Image Reference* so that your mesh matches its shape):

[image]

Unwrap, put your UV over the image in the *UV Editor*:

[image]

Now that your UV is ready you can get rid of your shape key if you want.

Comment: what do you mean?  ;)   I saw this method several days ago, I don't remember where but I found it pretty smart

Comment: aha sorry, but I count on you for the complicated solution  ^^

Comment: Miiiaow!  I think I detect a backhander :D

Comment: Thank you so much trying!

Comment: so did it work?